# Trigger a "button onClick" with a keypress with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a button that has the onclick event. 
How can I trigger it with a particular keypress?
I'm stumped. ~:(

in the html

```
<button id="upButt" onclick='library.cmd()'>Up Direction</button>
```

in the jQuery

```
$(function() {
var e = $.Event('keypress');
e.which = 68;  //UP key
$('#pre').trigger(e);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created JSfiddle link for the same:-

http://jsfiddle.net/c2S5d/26/

Code:-

```
$(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        switch (e.which) {
            case 38: // up key
                alert("up key event called")
                $("#upButt").trigger("click")
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You are my lord and savior @devendra-soni

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for enter keypress:
http://jsfiddle.net/qmruwn0a/

```
<input type="text">
<button id="btn">Click</button>

$('input').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) { //for key up use 38 
        $('#btn').trigger('click');
    }
});

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    alert("click");
});
```

change the e.which value to any key code you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work with any key add this to the button

```
onkeypress="this.onclick()"
```

Comment: However, keep in mind, this will also be called by the TAB key, so it's not ideal for accessibility.